# Google Translate, translate="no"

Tags: html, google-translate

I have a Help.htm file for my App which translates reasonably well with Google Translate. I want to mark the menu items as Do Not Translate but none of the HTML tags that i found and tried would work. For the following i used the Google Translate website - it translated where i did not expect! as the following example shows.

```
Email us at <span class="notranslate">sales at mydomain dot com</span>

Écrivez-nous à <span class="notranslate">ventes à mydomain dot com</span>
```

I found a couple similar no translate tags but same results. What am I missing here?

Here is a "real life" example, from my help file. I copied this into the Google translate, chose French and clicked on Translate ...

```
Then from the Options Menu choose one of:
<ul>
    <li><span class="notranslate">Help</span></li>
    <li><span class="notranslate">Browse WWW</span></li>
    <li><span class="notranslate">Load HTML Text</span></li>
    <li><span class="notranslate">Get Connection State</span></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the :( translation to French ...

```
Ensuite, dans le menu Options, choisissez l'une des:
<ul>
     <li> <span class = "notranslate"> Aide </ span> </ li>
     <li> <span class = "notranslate"> Parcourir WWW </ span> </ li>
     <li> <span class = "de notranslate"> Load HTML texte </ span> </ li>
     <li> <span class = "de notranslate"> Obtenez Connection État </ span> </ li>
```

Control K not working consistently for me. Nope, my keyboard is messing up. Time for a new one. Hope you can fix for me :)

Here is mine with `<span translate="no">`, followed by actual examples from 3 professional HTML websites; none of these work for me ...

```
Then from the Options Menu choose one of:
<ul>
    <li><span translate="no">Help</span> </li>
    <li><span translate="no">Browse WWW</span></li>
    <li><span translate="no">Load HTML Text</span></li>
    <li><span translate="no">Get Connection State</span></li>
</ul>

<Puis dans le menu Options, choisissez l'une des:
<ul>
     <li> <span translate = "no"> Aide </ span> </ li>
     <li> <span traduire = "no"> Parcourir WWW </ span> </ li>
     <li> <span translate = "no"> Load HTML texte </ span> </ li>
     <li> <span translate = "no"> Obtenez Connection État </ span> </ li>
</ ul>
```

1. From the official Google Webmaster Central Blog ...

   Email us at `<span class="notranslate">sales at mydomain dot com</span>`

   Écrivez-nous à `<span class = "notranslate"> ventes à mydomain dot com </span>`
2. From w3schools.com ...

   Don't translate this!

   This can be translated to any language.

   translate = "no"> Ne pas traduire cette!

   Cela peut être traduit en aucune langue.
3. From w3.org ...

   ## Using HTML's translate attribute

   Utilisation de HTML  translate  attribut

I thought at first the above worked but translate in English == translate in French :(

```
<h1>Using HTML's <span class="kw" translate="no">They Cheated</span> attribute</h1>

<h1> Utilisation de HTML <le span class = "kw" translate = "no"> qu'ils ont triché </ span> attribut </ h1>
```

Comment: Did you try <span class="e;notranslate"e;> ? https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/faq

Comment: @NickBartlett: since that's invalid HTML, I'd guess it's an escaping error from whatever markup they use internally and should read `class="notranslate"`, which the OP tried?

Comment: Hopefully? Seemed pretty strange to me. Also, it was mentioned in the title, but not the question ; I assume you tried `<span translate="no">` with no luck?

Comment: Google Cloud Translate is not an option since it costs a non-trivial amount of $s. I had tried the <span translate="no"> with no luck but have done so again and documented above. This is quite frustrating. I cannot see anything i am doing incorrectly. It seems to work for everyone else.

Comment: any chance you can post your whole Help.html (or at least the headers) or provide a fiddle with the not working example?

Comment: The actual help file has no headers. It is just plain, simple HTML - no tags except for H1, H2, B, U, BR, UL. Really nothing else except the paragraphs of text. I put it into the Google Translate at https://translate.google.ca/ It worked perfectly except that it is clear that i must have it not translate the item that refer to menu choices in my App.

Comment: The help file is plain text paragraphs with a few HTML tags H1, H2, B, U, BR, UL. I put it into the Google Translate at https://translate.google.ca/ It worked except that i must have it not translate the items that refer to menu choices in my App.

So i tried the two versions of NO TRANSLATE and was shocked when neither worked - after i found them on professional HTML websites including Google Webmaster Central Blog where they claim it works

Please, go to the Google Translate site and try it yourself. Been a computer programmer for 50 years. Lots of frustrations. But this is really annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did eventually determine what is the actual problem. It is that the markup will only be recognised as a signal not to translate the text if it is a page of an HTML website that you put through Google Translate. The translator interface at https://translate.google.com doesn't recognise that the pasted text should be interpreted as HTML code.